# Loading a plugin in a post template without using wp_head()

Tags: plugins, wp-head

I've created a custom post template for a specific purpose. Didn't include `get_header()` and `get_footer()` as I only wanted a blank template.
Problem is: I want to load monster insights plugin.

Adding `wp_head` and then removing the unwanted parts seems a long route and still, there are elements I wasn't able to remove, so looking for a simpler approach by just skipping the get_header and only include the plugin that I need on that post template.

Thank you!

Comment: Plugins aren't sandboxed in any way, once WP gets to the template part all the plugins are already loaded, and their code isn't separated from eachother. It's like taking 5 boxes of grain and dumping it all in a mixer, you can't pick and choose unless it's a specific hook or example. Even then, by the time it's deciding which template to load it's too late to most of that

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: In the custom template, I do not want any stylesheet or script that I add myself.
The template needs to be a simple <html><head></head><body><body></html>. In <head> only monster insights.

Why someone would want that? tbh, I have no idea. Its for someone (will ask though).

After trying hours and hours of manually dequeuing and deregistering stylesheets... there were still some that I couldn't so thought of just not using the get_header at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some point you must understand.

1. Monster Insights loads scripts to handle the analytics
2. Scripts are being loaded either header or footer
3. In order to load the scripts in your template you must include `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`
4. You may disable one of them by testing one by one.
5. Another option could be hard coding analytics script in your template file. That ways you still will be able to track everything.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, currently thats what I'm doing, to hard code the analytics. Just wanted to learn if there is any other way to do it by an action etc.